# Is it correct to use "delivery day" for a birth day?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use "delivery day" for a birthday? I have a colleague (Not a native English speaker as me) that is convinced that it is correct.

Comment: If it hasn't happened yet, it's the ***due date*** - normally the date on which the baby is expected to be born naturally, but it might be there's a "scheduled date" for a caesarean section or when labour will be "induced" early for some reason. In the days and weeks afterwards, it's more likely to be *"When was he born?"* rather than *"What is his birth date?"*. We don't normally refer to the baby's "birthday" until he's had one or two.

Comment: While *technically* valid, I'd probably imagine the baby being brought in by USPS.

Comment: I think I would say a native English speaker like me, not as me. And I would capitalize the word English.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski: Well, just as we ask *When was he born?* rather than *What is his birth date?*, we'd normally ask *When is the baby due?* rather than *What is the baby's due date?*

Comment: @Lambie: I assume the OP means that ***like himself***, his colleague ***is not*** a native Anglophone (*neither* of them are).

Comment: @FumbleFingers delivery date is the date a baby is delivered. due date is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Question:
Is it correct to use "delivery day" for a birth day? I have a colleague (Not a native English speaker as me) that is convinced that it is correct.

No, it isn't. delivery day is the day a mother gives birth to a baby. The date on which that happens becomes the child's **birthday** or **date of birth**. A birthday is a year later. But the date of birth is the delivery day.

Comment: A birthday is typically understood to be the *anniversary* of a birth, not the actual day of birth itself. Your first birthday occurs when you turn 1 year old, not the day you are born. A date of birth is a unique point in time and requires a year, but a birthday happens every year and is just a month and day. The month/day/year a child is born is their date of birth, the month/day they are born is their birthday, but their date of birth is not their first birthday.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The date of birth becomes the birthday. The next time it comes around.  I did say: that date **becomes** birthday. It does not mean that that day is a birthday. A date of birth does not require a year. A baby is born on 10/15/2023. On the 20th, you'd say his or her date of birth was 10/15.

Comment: Any form requiring DOB will be incomplete with only a month and day. The term can be used informally interchangeably with birthday, but date of birth often has a more specific meaning. A govennment employee may ask for your date of birth, but not your birthday, while your friend would not ask for your date of birth  instead of your birthday.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Not in my example it does not. And you don't need a year if it's the same year. obviously. You can say the year if you choose, of course. The main point though is that delivery day is wrong here. It just means the day the baby is delivered.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Birth day is not birthday. You are not adding to my answer at all.